# Календарь (логика)

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Добрый день. Уже 4й день мучаюсь в попытках воссоздать логику календаря во вкладке день. 
[image]

Ребята может вы знаете OpenSource порграммы где можно посмотреть на логику построения даной модели.

p.s Зарание спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я так понимаю что Вы хотите сделать подобие календаря и органайзера в одном приложении. Если так, то посмотрите в сторону КДЕ (Линукс) (там есть Контакт и Календарь, а также исходники к ними) или тот же ГНОМ из Линукса. Возможно чтото даже Вам там понравится в струтуре приложения и перетянете себе.